# Intermittent "TypeError: "exports" is read-only" error with Webpack and Vue-CLI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, node-modules, vue-cli

I have a Vue-CLI app which was working fine until recently. Now, sometimes this message appears in the console, and the rest of the app fails to load:

```
TypeError: "exports" is read-only
```

The direct cause appears to be one of my modules, which uses `module.exports` to export its default function. [I understand that](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3997) Webpack (which Vue CLI uses) reduced support for `module.exports`, at least in the case of a module which also contains ES2015 `import` statements. But that's [not the case here](http://npmjs.com/package/mapbox-gl-utils). And Webpack sometimes compiles it just fine.

What's particularly weird is it's intermittent. Generally I can make the problem go away temporarily by `rm -rf node_modules; npm install`. (Yarn install doesn't seem as reliable). But then it comes back.

What could be the cause? Perhaps two competing dependencies? My package.json looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@turf/turf": "^5.1.6",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.3",
    "color": "^3.1.0",
    "mapbox-gl": "^0.50.0",
    "mapbox-gl-utils": "^0.4.0",
    "thenify": "^3.3.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-carousel": "^0.16.0-rc2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.2.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

and my vue.config.js is (simplified):

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('eslint')
      .use('eslint-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        options.configFile = path.resolve(__dirname, ".eslintrc.js");
        return options;
      })
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([ 
        { ... }          
    ]
  }
}
```

I suspect, without being certain, that the problem is triggered when I make updates in my module, which is linked using `npm link`.

Using Vue CLI version 2.1.1.

As a workaround, if I use an ES2015 `export` statement instead, yes, the app works, but then I can't run my test suite with NodeJS.

I would love any suggestions for how to make my environment more stable so this intermittent problem doesn't recur.

Comment: I confirm this issue seems to be due to using npm link. Webpack is having issues with symlinked dependencies. I've been struggling with this for some hours now and realize it is working on freshly installing published version of my module, but failing when linking it using npm link.

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3227

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3227 this is due to some configurable behaviour. Add this in your vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.symlinks(false)
  }
}
```

It's working in my case.

Comment: Thank you, that's awesome. I did work out that it was definitely symlinks that were the problem, and was using the workaround of simply copying local updates rather than symlinks.

Comment: your welcome ... I was stumbling over this issue some months ago and back then I was starting copying stuff as well which is so much PITA ...

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem even after adding

```
chainWebpack: (config) => {
  config.resolve.symlinks(false)
}
```

to my vue.config.js

To resolve, I deleted my node_modules folder and ran a fresh `npm install`